# In jQuery, how do I prevent multiple clicks from executing my code multiple times?

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, mouseevent

For examle, if I had the following code:

```
$("#divTest").append(variable);
```

and the intended goal is to display a piece of information once a button was clicked, how do I handle users that are impatient or otherwise feel the need to click more than once (thus producing multiple copies) before the code is executed?

I'll clarify if need be.

Thanks!

Comment: At least, you should have include a click handler code, no?!

Comment: I have not, and to be honest I've no idea how to implement that into an existing project. Can it be easily done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in click function

```
 $("#button").click( function()
           {
              $("#divTest").empty().append(variable);
           }
        );
```

Comment: There's no `.clear()` method in the documentation. Did you mean [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)?

Comment: I can't actually find a `.clear` function on the jQuery website. Perhaps you mean `.empty` which would do what you want? (Edit: Blazemonger beat me to it ;) )

Comment: Thankyou mates.Edited.Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: And I just started searching in the jquery source for a "clear" function :)

Comment: @MarcelGwerder  sorry Marcel. In a hurry i made a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the jQuery [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function. That would only allow the click handler to be used once.

```
$("#button").one("click",function() { /* -- Your code here -- */ });
```

---

Alternatively, if the button is actually an `input` or `button` tag, you could set the `disabled` attribute. Below is some more information from [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-disabled) about the `disabled` attribute.

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not available for interaction.
>   In particular, the click event will not be dispatched on disabled controls.
>   Also, a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also unbind the click event on the first click

```
$(#button).click(function() {
    $("#divTest").append(variable);
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

Comment: Curious, should I want to be able to click it again,      $(this).bind("click"); ?

Comment: @MrS1ck you can unbind the event then bind it again inside the event handler to do something else.